# VBA: Placing the values of different variables across a row of cells

Tags: excel, vba

This macro is a "save" function that takes a given set of parameters in a model and saves them across a row in a table. I'm able to "move" across the row using a for loop and offset, but I'm unsure of how to save different variables in each cell.

```
Sub TestOffset()

Dim Counter As Integer
Dim StartingCell As Range
Set StartingCell = Range("C10")

For Counter = 0 To 15

StartingCell.Offset(0, Counter).Value = 1

Next Counter

End Sub
```

This is my current code, but instead of putting "1" into every cell, I'd like to put different variables such as Demand, Supply, Cost, Capacity in each. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Choose` function

```
Sub TestOffset()

    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim StartingCell As Range

    Dim Demand As Long, Supply As Long, Cost As Long, Capacity As Long

    Set StartingCell = Range("C10")

    Demand = 5
    Supply = 6
    Cost = 7
    Capacity = 8

    For Counter = 1 To 4

    StartingCell.Offset(0, Counter).Value = Choose(Counter, Demand, Supply, Cost, Capacity)

    Next Counter

End Sub
```

---

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Variables Array

Make sure you put the vntVariables line after the values for the variables have changed.

```
Sub TestOffset()

    Dim vntVariables As Variant   ' Variables Array
    Dim Counter As Integer        ' Columns Counter / Array Rows Counter
    Dim StartingCell As Range     ' Starting Cell

    Dim Demand As Long
    Dim Supply As Long
    Dim Cost As Double ' Maybe Currency
    Dim Capacity As Long

    Set StartingCell = Range("C10")

    Demand = 3
    Supply = 7
    Cost = 2.99
    Capacity = 10

    vntVariables = Array(Demand, Supply, Cost, Capacity)

    For Counter = 0 To UBound(vntVariables)

        StartingCell.Offset(0, Counter).Value = vntVariables(Counter)

    Next

End Sub
```